# Short hand if statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, shorthand-if

Is there a shorter version of the following:

Using ASP.NET MVC, this is in the HTML page

```
<%= IsTrue ? Html.Image("~/images/myimage.gif") : "" %>
```

I know I'm only really writing 3 extra characters, just wondering if there is something better.

Comment: What are you trying to shorten it to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not, the ? operator is itself a short hand for the if else statement.

Comment: The conditional operator can only be used as an expression, while `if` is obviously a statement. One is not short hand for the other as they are conceptually different.

Answer (score 8):

It might be acceptable to create html helper:

```
public static string ImageIf(this HtmlHelper helper, condition, url){
    return condition ? helper.Image(url) : "";
}
```

usage:

```
<%= Html.ImageIf(IsTrue, "~/images/myimage.gif") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not for the case you outlined.

If you are doing a null check on `A` you could write `var b = A ?? string.Empty;`

Kindness,

Dan

Comment: This one is handy when passing model to strongly typed partial because if null is provided - partial automagically receives model from view.